EB Deploy Next.js | An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Run Docker Container]
I've been attempting to put my Next.js application online using Elastic Beanstalk to no avail.  I'm not able to understand the problem I'm facing given the error I see in the eb-engine.log.  I'm getting this error when using eb deploy in the root directory of my application. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the command line error
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2024-09-25 23:16:21    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2024-09-25 23:16:56    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2024-09-25 23:17:44    ERROR   Instance deployment: The Docker container unexpectedly ended after it was started.
2024-09-25 23:17:44    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2024-09-25 23:17:44    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ea7b4ec56e38f4fa] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2024-09-25 23:17:45    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2024-09-25 23:17:45    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ea7b4ec56e38f4fa'. Aborting the operation.
2024-09-25 23:17:45    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.  

Here is the error I receive from /var/log/eb-engine.log
2024/09/25 23:17:44.673921 [INFO] Running command: docker ps | grep -q 973e30dbc405
2024/09/25 23:17:44.707815 [ERROR] docker container quit unexpectedly on 2024-09-25 23:17:44.705841294 +0000 UTC: Command docker ps | grep -q 973e30dbc405 failed with error exit status 1
2024/09/25 23:17:44.708423 [INFO] Running command: docker logs 973e30dbc405
2024/09/25 23:17:44.741469 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Run Docker Container]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to run the docker container 973e30dbc405: Command docker ps | grep -q 973e30dbc405 failed with error exit status 1 

2024/09/25 23:17:44.741480 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2024/09/25 23:17:44.742845 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment: The Docker container unexpectedly ended after it was started.","timestamp":1727306264708,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1727306264741,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

Here is my Dockerfile
FROM node:20.12.2-alpine as base

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ make py3-pip libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY package*.json /app/frontend
EXPOSE 3000

FROM base as builder
WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY . /app/frontend
RUN npm run build


FROM base as production
WORKDIR /app/frontend

ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm ci

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
USER nextjs


COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/frontend/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/frontend/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/frontend/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/frontend/public ./public

CMD npm start

# I don't know why I need this line here if I'm not doing a dev build.
# If I leave it out I'll get an error that says: 
# failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
FROM base as dev
# ENV NODE_ENV=development
# RUN npm install 
# COPY . .
# CMD npm run dev

Here is my .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: docker-frontend-env
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: docker-frontend
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: null
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application

